# Is there a Google API for searching geotagged images?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm looking for the Google equivalent of [Flickr's Photo Search API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html). Does such a thing even exist?

Looking at [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/) I can click the arrow in the bottom right corner to bring up images in my location, and highlighting an image shows where it was taken on the map. I want to access these images through a web application (without the map).

I've been scanning over the [web API's](https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started/) available from Google but I can't tell which one, if any, would provide the data I'm after, nor can I find any examples...

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Or let me know if this feature simply isn't available?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Places API and used [Places Photo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_photos)?

The Photo service gives you access to the millions of photos stored in the Places and Google+ Local database. When you get place information using a Place Details request, photo references will be returned for relevant photographic content.